# how to save the spinner position?

Tags: position, spinner, save

In my app I have a spinner with set of units, if I select a value from the spinner & change the position from portrait to landscape, value is as it is, but the problem is when I am changing the orientation from landscape to portrait my spinner value is changing  how to save the spinner position & how to resolve it...

Looking forward to your valuable suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: What sort of application are you talking about? Java, ASP.Net, iPhone, Android, WPF?